# i'm trying restore an community with dspace packager

Tags: dspace

i'm trying restore an community with dspace packager -r -s -k -a -t AIP

returning this error:

> This may take a while, please check your logs for ongoing status while
>   we process each package.
>   org.dspace.content.crosswalk.MetadataValidationException: Bad number
>   value in PREMIS object/objectCharacteristics/size: 2237780334     at
>   org.dspace.content.crosswalk.PREMISCrosswalk.ingest(PREMISCrosswalk.java:122)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.crosswalk.PREMISCrosswalk.ingest(PREMISCrosswalk.java:88)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.METSManifest.crosswalkXmd(METSManifest.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.METSManifest.crosswalkBitstream(METSManifest.java:1310)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSIngester.addBitstreams(AbstractMETSIngester.java:814)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSIngester.ingestObject(AbstractMETSIngester.java:494)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSIngester.ingest(AbstractMETSIngester.java:228)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageIngester.ingestAll(AbstractPackageIngester.java:145)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageIngester.ingestAll(AbstractPackageIngester.java:195)
>     at
>   org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageIngester.ingestAll(AbstractPackageIngester.java:195)
>     at org.dspace.app.packager.Packager.ingest(Packager.java:515)   at
>   org.dspace.app.packager.Packager.main(Packager.java:427)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:226)
>     at
>   org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:78)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "2237780334"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   org.dspace.content.crosswalk.PREMISCrosswalk.ingest(PREMISCrosswalk.java:112)
>     ... 17 more org.dspace.content.crosswalk.MetadataValidationException:
>   Bad number value in PREMIS object/objectCharacteristics/size:
>   2237780334

How to solve this?

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/crosswalk/PREMISCrosswalk.java

Answer (score 2):

That number would fit in a Long but not an Integer, so Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException.  Basically the object is too large to have its declared size checked against the actual Bitstream.  The code is buggy:  Bitstream.getSize returns a long, which is plenty large enough for a mere couple of billion, and ought to be compared to a Long.  PREMISCrosswalk ought to be using Long.parseLong.  Please file an issue at https://jira.duraspace.org/ including the stack trace that you show above, and/or link to this question.  Thank you for bringing this problem to our attention.

If you wish, you should be able to get past this problem by patching that single line (PREMISCrosswalk.java:112) changing it from

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(ssize);
```

to

```
long ssize = Long.parseLong(ssize);
```

Comment: As it was critical situation in the system, and there was the need to restore the community in time by the unavailability of the system. I ended up doing a backup of the file and i removed it in the restore worked normally. I will do a new backup simulation and I will try to restore it in the community and report the problem.